# can't access localhost

Tags: localhost, wamp

I used to be able to access my localhost through my wampserver but not anymore. It just opens up a blank page in every browser that keeps on loading. I did some research and noticed this problem usually occurs when a program using port 80 (such as Skype) is interfering. Well I do have skype but I unchecked the "use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" option so that's not it. I even typed netstat in the cmd screen to check which program could be using port 80 but it's open so I suspect the problem to be elsewhere. Besides, even after editing httpd.conf and swapping my port to 8080 it still does nothing (and yes I surfed to localhost:8080). I don't think my hosts file is to blame either. It clearly says "127.0.0.1 localhost" and there's no hash tag in front of it. I already reinstalled my wampserver and even tried xampp but no dice. Can anyone please tell me if I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont find which service binds the port 80 ; edit you httpd.conf and change the Listen parameter from 80 to 81 for example.